# File names with spaces as bulk arguments

Tags: file, bash, shell

If I have a list of files, some of which have spaces in their names, generated from, say:

```
find . -iname "*hs" | grep foo
```

How can I pass them as arguments to a single process like `process name1 name2 ...`?

Note that I want to pass all file names as individual arguments to a single process, so standard `for f in *` solutions won't work

Comment: [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs)

Comment: @MattBall: I tried with `xargs`, but it's splitting the filenames with spaces into multiple arguments

Comment: Will you always be using 'find' to generate the filenames?

Comment: @morgant: For this use-case, yes! But of course it would be nice to know a general solution

Comment: 'find -print0' used in conjunction with 'xargs -0' should do the trick.

Comment: @morgant: Thanks! I'm almost there...

Comment: For people searching for this later: my final solution is in a comment under @JonathanLeffler's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -iname "*hs*" -exec grep foo {} +

find . -iname "*hs*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo
```

Both work; the first might even be a little more efficient, unless the `+` option groups fewer files into a command line than `xargs` does.

If you're generating the file names via shell globbing, then:

```
grep foo *hs*
```

preserves the spacing in file names.  Using `ls` to generate the names is very problematic.

---

#### Filtering names

> The grep command was meant to filter the list of filenames before the bulk process, not to search the contents of the files themselves.

So you want names that match both '*hs*' and '*foo*'?  In that case, you are best off using `find` still:

```
find . \( -iname "*hs*" -a -iname "*foo*" \) -exec grep foo {} +
```

Use the boolean capabilities of `find`.

#### GNU `grep` extensions `-Z` and `-z`

If you can't do that (your `grep` regex needs to be too complex for `find`), then you're in difficulties unless you've got a (hypothetical?) version of `grep` that will *read* 'lines' delimited by nulls.

> `-Z`, `--null`
>   Output  a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a
>   file name.  For example, `grep -lZ` outputs a zero byte after each file name instead of the
>   usual newline.  This option makes the output unambiguous, even in the presence of file names
>   containing unusual characters like newlines.  This option can be used with commands like
>   `find -print0`,  `perl -0`, `sort -z`, and `xargs -0` to process arbitrary file names, even
>   those that contain newline characters.

This is almost what's wanted, but not quite.  The POSIX 2008 [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function would be the tool to use; add a `-z` option to `grep` for the purpose, and then use `grep -lzZ ....` to filter the `find ... -print0` data before it is fed to `xargs -0`.

The quote above is from the manual page on Mac OS X 10.7.5, and the GNU `grep` is version 2.5.1.  Maybe a more recent version of GNU [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) is better equipped to help?

And lo and behold, GNU `grep` 2.14 supports the requisite option:

> `-z`, `--null-data`
>   Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the `-Z` or `--null` option, this option can be used with commands like ‘sort -z’ to process arbitrary file names.

#### Run a script from `find`

The other option, not to be ignored, is to create a script to be run by the `find` command:

```
find . -iname "*hs*" -exec ./list-foo +
```

Where the `list-foo` script might be:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in
    (*foo*) echo "$arg";;   # This will still cause problems
    esac
done
```

This identifies the files; the `echo` is sub-optimal.  Maybe you need to capture the names in an array, and then invoke the final command using the array:

```
array=( )
i=0
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in
    (*foo*) array[$((i++))]="$arg";;
    esac
done

if [ "$i" -gt 0 ]
then real_work "${array[@]}"
fi
```

Where `real_work` is the program (script?) that does the real work.  You can throw `list-foo` away once you're done with it, unless you're going to be doing the same filtering job over and over.

---

#### Globbing names that contain a space

You can glob names that contain a space by escaping the space:

```
rm -i -- *\ *
```

This expands to just the file names with spaces in the name, which helps in cleaning up a directory with file names containing files created for testing the answers to this question.

Comment: This is working in general, but I'm still tweaking it, as the `grep` command was meant to filter the list of filenames before the bulk process, not to search the contents of the files themselves

Comment: Ok, found the full answer! `find . -iname "*hs -print0 | grep -zZ foo | xargs -0 some-process` - this allows you to filter with `grep` in-between

Comment: Yup...and I found the same thing while you were at work, and wrote up that and some alternatives.  `bash` arrays can be quite useful; so can custom scripts.  But for your immediate purpose, a new enough version of GNU `grep` and the `-zZ` options is what you want.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer! Btw, my reason for piping through `grep` is to filter based on the directories the file is in -- e.g. find the "bar" in `find`'s result of "./foo/bar/file.hs"

Comment: Look up `-path` and `-ipath` in GNU [`find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Full-Name-Patterns); also the `-regex` option.  There's more than one way to do it — and that's before we start using Perl.

Comment: And, just an FYI (now I've compiled and tested GNU `grep` 2.14): the `-z` option is sufficient for your purpose.  The `-Z` option is appropriate for when you want `grep` to generate a list of null terminated file names from the list of files it is processing, not from the data it is processing.  A question of learning as we go...